# User has more privileges in redshift than shown by relevant query

Tags: redshift

Working in `Redshift`

```
dev=# SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges
WHERE  grantee = 'myser';
 table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | privilege_type
---------------+--------------+------------+----------------
(0 rows)
```

However the user is able to perform select on several randomly tested `pg_catalog` schema tables, e.g. `SELECT * FROM pg_class_info;`, `SELECT * FROM pg_class;` etc.

The only `GRANT` command I run after creating `myser` was:

```
GRANT SELECT ON stl_connection_log  TO myuser;
```

after setting

```
SET search_path TO pg_catalog;
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`information_schema.table_privileges` only shows the privileges that were directly granted to a role (user), not the privileges inherited through role membership.

Now most catalog tables have `SELECT` privileges granted to the special role `PUBLIC`, which stands for “everybody”, so every user can `SELECT` from catalog tables.

And if you feel tempted to change that, don't. It will affect the usability of your database.

Comment: So I cannot create a user that has SELECT in ONLY ONE `pg_catalog` table?

Comment: No, that is not possible.